# Where I can configure the port number for a particular war file to run on a jboss instance?

Tags: java, xml, port, wildfly, war

I have configured two ports for a single wildfly instance ie., 8080 and 8081. When I deploy the .war file to the deployments folder of this wildfly instance, the application is available on both 8080 and 8081 ports. I want only one war file (without disturbing other war files in this deployments folder) to be run on 8081. And it should not be available on 8080. But now it is available on both ports. From the java web application is it possible to configure that the application should be run on only 8081 port?

Do I need to set any values in jboss-web.xml or jboss-beans.xml?

Comment: Which JBoss version is it?

Comment: wildfly-8.2.1.Final

Comment: Please check your `standalone.xml` file, look for the `socket-binding-group` element.

Comment: In the socket binding element I have given as  <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="httpSLWS" port="${jboss.http.port:8081}"/>  . And both these are there in http-listener. I need to have in this manner only , to have two ports for single wildfly instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Change the socket-binding in the configuration file.

   ```
   <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
   ```

   `offset 0` means 8080. You can specify the value of offset say 100 then your application will be accessible on 8180
2. Set the system property on startup. The property names are listed in the configuration file.

   ```
   standalone.bat -Djboss.http.port=8180
   ```